# "Expected type 'Type', got 'Type[Type]' instead"

Tags: python

My class has a project where we have to build a database. I keep running into this error where python asks expected a type of the same kind that I gave it ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmU03.png)
)

It says `Expected type 'TableEntry', got 'Type[TableEntry]' instead`

TableEntry is a dataclass instance (as per my assignment). I am only calling it for it's creation `newTable = Table(id, TableEntry)`
Where Table is another dataclass with an id and data with type `TableEntry*`.

*I am required to complete the assignment using this format, and am only asking about the syntax, not how to format it

Comment: You need to show us the actual code that is causing the problem - enough for us to tell what you are actually doing. Ideally, enough that we could reproduce the problem by running the code locally.

Comment: You'll need to include your code to be sure, but it looks like you might be passing the class TableEntry rather than an instance of the TableEntry. If you include your code we may be able to help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you see an error like this:

> Expected type 'TableEntry', got 'Type[TableEntry]' instead

it generally means that in the body of your code you said `TableEntry` (the name of the type) rather than `TableEntry()` (an expression that constructs an actual object of that type).

Answer (score 0):

If your formatter understands sphinx type docstrings (pep257), then if you have code like this:

```py
newTable = Table(TableEntry)
```

Then you'll need docstrings like

```py
class TableEntry:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Table:
    def __init__(self, table_entry):
        """Descrption.
        
        :param table_entry:
        :type table_entry: type[TableEntry]
        """
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because you are passing in a **Type** (`TableEntry`) when an **Instance** (`TableEntry()`) of the class is expected. Notice the trailing parenthesis in the latter one.

I've reproduced the error with a basic demo:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class TableEntry:
    name: str
    value: int


@dataclass
class Table:
    id: int
    TableEntry: TableEntry


id = 3
newTable = Table(id, TableEntry)
```

Here, you were passing the **Type** `TableEntry`; **not an instance of** `TableEntry`.

**To solve the issue**:

**1-** You can either create the `TableEntry` instance in place:

```
newTable = Table(id, TableEntry('daxti', 23))
```

or

**2-** You can create an instance and then pass it into the `Table` object:

```
newTableEntry = TableEntry("daxti", 23)
newTable = Table(id, newTableEntry)
```